# Python: How do I match keys then multiply the values of a key-value pair value with values from another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two python dictionaries. One is a nested dictionary and one is a regular dictionary like so:

```
dict1 = {"12345": {"a": 2, "b": 4, "c": 3, "d": 5}, "67891": {"c": 5, "d": 4, "e": 2, "f": 1}}
dict2 = {"12345": 3, "67891": 4}
```

I want to multiply each value inside dict1 with the dict2 values where the keys between dict1 and dict2 match. The result will be like so:

```
# Desired output:
dict1 = {"12345": {"a": 6, "b": 12, "c": 9, "d": 15}, "67891": {"c": 20, "d": 16, "e": 8, "f": 4}}
```

I tried to input this code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    v= {v: v*dict2[k])}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a loop and `dict` comprehension

**Ex:**

```
dict1 = {"12345": {"a": 2, "b": 4, "c": 3, "d": 5}, "67891": {"c": 5, "d": 4, "e": 2, "f": 1}}
dict2 = {"12345": 3, "67891": 4}

for k, v in dict2.items():
    dict1[k] = {m: n*v for m, n in dict1[k].items()}

print(dict1)
```

**Output:**

```
{'12345': {'a': 6, 'b': 12, 'c': 9, 'd': 15},
 '67891': {'c': 20, 'd': 16, 'e': 8, 'f': 4}}
```

Comment: Is this going to match the keys though? What if I have different key value pairs or different order in dict2 or dict1?

Comment: Yes, it does. in the dict comprehension, I am looking for the key `dict1[k].items()`